# Multiple Filter in One Table

Tags: reactjs

This is my table data from where the data comes

```
  let mainArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "foo",
      city: "dallas",
      category: "one",
      type: "A",
      active: "FALSE",
      // state: "guj"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "bar",
      city: "dallas",
      category: "one",
      type: "B",
      active: "FALSE",
      //state: "guj"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "jim",
      city: "san francisco",
      category: "one",
      type: "B",
      active: "TRUE",
      //state: "raj"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "jane",
      city: "denver",
      category: "two",
      type: "C",
      active: "FALSE",
      //state: "mah"
    },
  ];
```

This is my JSX part

```
<div className="App">
      {mainArray.map((u, key) => (
        <>
          <div>
            <div>
              City : {u.city} <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </div>
            <br></br>
          </div>
          <>
            <div>
              Category :{u.category} <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </div>
            <br></br>
          </>
          <>
            <div>
              Type :{u.type} <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </div>
            <br></br>
          </>
          <>
            <div>
              Active :{u.active} <input type="checkbox"></input>
            </div>
            <br></br>
          </>
        </>
      ))}
      Name : <input type="text" name="" />
      <br></br>
      <table border="5px" align="center">
        <thead>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>City</td>
          <td>Category</td>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {mainArray.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <>
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                  <td>{item.city}</td>
                  <td>{item.category}</td>
                  <td>{item.type}</td>
                  <td>{item.active}</td>
                </tr>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

My Question is that I want all the data to be filtered If I checked.
If I checked any one of the data then it should be filtered, and changes occurs in table.

I used w3School code for my page and it works fine but it only filters one column, don’t know how create loops but hopping there is easier solution.

here is the link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nw38ow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some modifications in your code. I think this is what you want

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
    city: [],
    category: [],
    type: [],
    active: [],
  });

  const [filterState, setFilterState] = useState({
    name: '',
    city: [],
    category: [],
    type: [],
    active: [],
  });

  let mainArray = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'foo',
      city: 'dallas',
      category: 'one',
      type: 'A',
      active: 'FALSE',
      // state: "guj"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'bar',
      city: 'dallas',
      category: 'one',
      type: 'B',
      active: 'FALSE',
      //state: "guj"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'jim',
      city: 'san francisco',
      category: 'one',
      type: 'B',
      active: 'TRUE',
      //state: "raj"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'jane',
      city: 'denver',
      category: 'two',
      type: 'C',
      active: 'FALSE',
      //state: "mah"
    },
  ];
  const handleCity = (e) => {
    let arr = filterState.city;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (!arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.push(e.target.value);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          city: arr,
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          city: arr,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const handleCategory = (e) => {
    let arr = filterState.category;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (!arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.push(e.target.value);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          category: arr,
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          category: arr,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const handleType = (e) => {
    let arr = filterState.type;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (!arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.push(e.target.value);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          type: arr,
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          type: arr,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const handleActive = (e) => {
    let arr = filterState.active;
    if (e.target.checked) {
      if (!arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.push(e.target.value);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          active: arr,
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (arr.indexOf(e.target.value) > -1) {
        arr.splice(arr.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
        setFilterState({
          ...filterState,
          active: arr,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  const getCities = (cities) => (
    <div>
      <div>
        City :{' '}
        {cities
          .filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)
          .map((city) => (
            <>
              {city}{' '}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value={city}
                onChange={(e) => handleCity(e)}
              ></input>
            </>
          ))}
      </div>
      <br></br>
    </div>
  );

  const getCategories = (categories) => (
    <div>
      Category :
      {categories
        .filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)
        .map((category) => (
          <>
            {category}{' '}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={category}
              onChange={(e) => handleCategory(e)}
            ></input>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  );

  const getTypes = (types) => (
    <div>
      Type :
      {types
        .filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)
        .map((type) => (
          <>
            {type}{' '}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={type}
              onChange={(e) => handleType(e)}
            ></input>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  );

  const getActive = (actives) => (
    <div>
      Active :
      {actives
        .filter((item, i, ar) => ar.indexOf(item) === i)
        .map((active) => (
          <>
            {active}{' '}
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value={active}
              onChange={(e) => handleActive(e)}
            ></input>
          </>
        ))}
    </div>
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    let city = filters.city;
    let category = filters.category;
    let type = filters.type;
    let active = filters.active;

    mainArray.forEach((item) => {
      city.push(item.city);
      category.push(item.category);
      type.push(item.type);
      active.push(item.active);
    });
    setFilters({
      ...filters,
      city: city,
      category: category,
      type: type,
      active: active,
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      {getCities(filters.city)}
      {getCategories(filters.category)}
      <br></br>
      {getTypes(filters.type)}
      <br></br>
      {getActive(filters.active)}
      <br></br>
      Name :{' '}
      <input
        type="text"
        name=""
        onChange={(e) =>
          setFilterState({ ...filterState, name: e.target.value })
        }
      />
      <br></br>
      <table border="5px" align="center">
        <thead>
          <td>ID</td>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>City</td>
          <td>Category</td>
          <td>Type</td>
          <td>Status</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {mainArray
            .filter(
              (item) =>
                (item.name.includes(filterState.name) ||
                  filterState.name == '') &&
                (filterState.city.includes(item.city) ||
                  filterState.city.length == 0) &&
                (filterState.category.includes(item.category) ||
                  filterState.category.length == 0) &&
                (filterState.type.includes(item.type) ||
                  filterState.type.length == 0) &&
                (filterState.active.includes(item.active) ||
                  filterState.active.length == 0)
            )
            .map((item, i) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{item.id}</td>
                    <td>{item.name}</td>
                    <td>{item.city}</td>
                    <td>{item.category}</td>
                    <td>{item.type}</td>
                    <td>{item.active}</td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's a thing I want but one thing also I want that above table, the city name, category etc have duplicate value like city have 2 time dallas value , type have 2 time B, etc all this repetating values, I want that this repetating values should not comes only unique value , I want to display....thanks in Advance

Comment: I have edited the code. Now it includes all the conditions you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: thanks, its works for me, In my main array If I want to add dynamic values and it should be render in table and above table values ? , it is possible for example In table, you write static values like, City , Category, active etc,If I want to add state : "Maharashta" in all the objects of array, in my main array then How it should be rendered in table and above table values, ??

Comment: Yes you can map Object keys and have whatever data you want. If any help requied keep me posted

Comment: Yes, I have Done this, but I cannot fix 1 bug, If I add data in only one object, there are 2 checkbox where added instead of one , how can I Fix?

Comment: I would like to see your code.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-acqrmr here is my code , If I add only one key value in my object whose id : 1 then two checkboxes are added

Answer (score 1):

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wehwz1?file=src/App.js)

I tried using state in react.

```
const [mainArray, setMainArray] = useState([values from mainArray ])

           <div>
              City : {u.city}{' '}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                value={u.city}
                onChange={(event) => filterData(event.target, 'city')}
              ></input>
            </div> 



 function filterData(target, type) {
    if (target.checked) {
      let result = mainArray.filter((res) => res[type] == target.value);
      setMainArray([...result]);
    }
  }
```

onClick of checkout mainArray state will be filtered

Comment: thanks, its works but If I unchecked the its not working, If I uncheck the original should not come.

Comment: when you uncheck original data should come ?

Comment: If I checked Denver, then Denver data shows me, but If I unchecked Denver Still show me only Denver Data,